# image view not showing the image with using thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bitmap

I'm using this code to show Images, as I run it without thread It works correctly but with using thread I just get Image views without any picture inside them. its important for me to use thread for this part of my program because its very slow :(
here is my code :

```
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.e("sara" , "this part takes time");


            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gallery_gridsq, parent, false);
            iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
          final File file = new File(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()).getPath());
            //File file = new File("/text.jpg");

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            try {
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
            try {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, options);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                }
            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is better if you use an image loading library like GLIDE (https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

It will take care of all the image loading issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AsyncTask`.

Doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the
>   UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

Do your heavy operation in `doInBackground()` and set the image to imageView in `onPostExecute()`.